# Maven pom to include importable jar from another project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a project creating a Utility jar using Maven and it is stored in the local repository. I want to import that jar into my Application project. Because Maven now puts BOOT-INF in-front of the class path, I put the following into the Utility Jar to generate an importable version.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--to be imported on other projects-->
                            <classifier>importable</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It's version 1.0 so it creates the following in the repository ...

```
utility-1.0-importable.jar
utility-1.0.jar
```

... and some other stuff.
The importable jar does NOT put BOOT-INF in-front of the directories for my classes and so that's the jar I want to include in my Application pom.xml.

I just don't know how to refer to it as the following refers to the utility-1.0.jar, which has the BOOT-INF and consequently the classes are not found.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>utility</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

How do I refer to the importable jar?
(This is all brand new and so the latest versions of everything are being used.)

I've been wading through heaps of posts about including dependent maven projects but they don't seem to explain just what precisely goes into the dependent project and what goes into the application project.

Comment: What's the problem when you are using it as a dependency in other project ? Maven will import it if your lib is present in your local .m2 folder.

Comment: Spring boot jars are finalized for deployment and not further consumption.  Reconsider your approach

Comment: Thanks Throbjorn. That is a good point. I really should have utility.jar that's just built with the maven-jar-plugin and then imported into my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the article https://www.baeldung.com/maven-artifact-classifiers, following dependency should work for you:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>utility</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <classifier>importable</classifier>
        </dependency>
```